# How to modify Quasar's slider value on change?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, slider, quasar

Consider the following code example (or this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9n3ahoy0/3/):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.11.10/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="q-app">
      <p>Test</p>
      <q-slider :model-value="sliderValue" :min="0" :max="100" @update:model-value="snap" label-always />
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.11.10/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
    <script>
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        setup() {
          return {
            sliderValue: Vue.ref(50),
          };
        },
        methods: {
          snap(value) {
            this.sliderValue = Math.round(value / 10) * 10;
            console.log(value, this.sliderValue);
          },
        },
      });
      app.use(Quasar);
      app.mount("#q-app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After moving the slider, it should jump to the next multiple of 10. (I know, there is a `step` prop for this, but this is not the point.) Sometime it works, especially when clicking somewhere on the slider track. But often the new value is ignored, even though it is correctly printed to the console.

How can I enforce a certain value change within the event handler?